# Convert the follwing bash script to sh

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    ary+=("$f")
done < <(find ~/project/jobs -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name "utils" -printf "\"%f\"\0")

(IFS=","; echo "[${ary[*]}]")
```

That is supposed to list the top level folder of the my_folder except the one named exclude.
It is made in bash, but I don't have bash on the machine I'm executing it.

Which result in giving me the error :

> (On line 3) Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

I would like to convert it in sh so I would be able to execute it.

I put it on https://www.shellcheck.net/

and it gave me the errors :

```
Line 4:
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
                   ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, read -d is undefined.

Line 5:
    ary+=("$f")
    ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, += is undefined.
         ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, arrays are undefined.

Line 6:
done < <(find ~/project/jobs -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name "utils" -printf "\"%f\"\0")
       ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, process substitution is undefined.

Line 8:
(IFS=","; echo "[${ary[*]}]")
                 ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, array references are undefined.
```

Is there a way to convert it to sh ? How would I proceed.

Comment: What is /bin/sh on your system: is it dash ?  check with 'ls -l /bin/sh'

Comment: Why not just change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`? Or do you really want to convert it to posix sh?

Comment: I want to execute this on a CircleCi build, it's a remote machine. It doesn't even have apt-get so I want to do it in sh.

Comment: @dash-o it answers me this /bin/sh -> /bin/busybox

Comment: All else aside, props for using shallcheck before posting the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need `find` for this at all. Since POSIX doesn't support arbitrary arrays, you can use the positional parameters in their place.

```
#!/bin/sh

set --   # Clear the positional parameters
cd ~/project/jobs

for d in */; do
  [ "$d" = "utils/" ] && continue
  set -- "$@" "\"${d%/}\""
done

(IFS=","; printf '[%s]\n' "$*")
```

If the script is going to exit immediately, you can drop the parentheses, as there won't be any harm in setting `IFS` globally.

---

As it appears you are trying to generate JSON, I would recommend the following if installing `jq` is at all an option:

```
cd ~/project/jobs
jq -n --args '$ARGS.positional | select(.!="utils/") | map(rtrimstr("/"))' */
```

Comment: Using your code I have a result like this [dummy_job/,second_job/,utils/], which is better than I currently have but I also would like to remove the / and put every foder between ".

Comment: I managed to put the folder name between " by putitng the "$d" like this "\"$d\"" but I don't see how removing the \ at the end of each folder.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the trailing `/`; I'll update. I added the explicit quoting as well.

Comment: Nice, could you just explain what does the set -- please ?

Comment: `set` just sets the positional arguments. At each step, we're appending the quoted directory name to the end of the accumulated arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If we just wanted to convert the original script, here it is :

```
#!/bin/sh
find ~/project/jobs -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name "utils" -printf "\"%f\"\n" | { \
sep=
while read -r f; do
    ary="$ary$sep$f"
    sep=,
done
echo "[$ary]"
}
```

**Explain**

Instead of process substitution, we use piping (|).

Also we have to group while-loop with the final echo.